# How To: Delete a row in Table storage using a DropDownList control ?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have a table named (LoginTable) which contains 3 columns: (Username, Password, Email).

I have a DropDownList control named (ddlUsers) which displays all the usernames in the table above. In other words, The DropDownList control (ddlUsers) populated from the Username column of the table named (LoginTable).

I have a button named (btnDelete), and I want that when a user selects a value/item from the DropDownList control (ddlUsers), and click the button, then that specific row will be deleted completely from the table (LoginTable).

Could you please guide me how to do that? Any code snippet please?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What's the PartitionKey/RowKey for the entity you wish to delete?

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I found the answer already